# Как вывести и сохранить несколько форм на одной странице?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть модель организации, у нее есть адреса(может быть несколько). как вывести эти две формы на одной странице и также иметь возможность сохранять и редактировать организацию?

```
class Industry(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(_('Название'),max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)
        verbose_name = _('Отрасль')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Отрасли')
    
    
class Entity(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(_('Заголовок'), max_length=255, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        _('Алиас'), max_length=150, db_index=True, unique=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Разрешены только латинские символы, цифры, символ подчеркивания и дефис (минус)'
        )
    )
    short_description = models.CharField(_('Короткое описание'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(_('Описание'), blank=True)
    test_field = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Тестовое поле'), max_length=4096)
    test_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,null=True, verbose_name=_('Тестовое поле 2'))
    industry = models.ForeignKey(
        Industry, verbose_name=_('Отрасль'), related_name='industries', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)
        verbose_name = _('Организация')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Организации')


class AddressClass(BaseModel):
    address = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Адрес'), blank=True, null=True)
    oktmo = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('ОКТМО'),max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Почтовый индекс'), max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(
        Entity, verbose_name=_('Организация'), related_name='addresses', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)


forms.py:
class EntityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    industry = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Industry.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('ordering', 'status')
        model = models.Entity


class PhysAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Формы для адресов"""
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('ordering', 'status', 'entity')
        model = models.PhysicalAddress
```

Comment: Выводите как `form1=EntityForm()` , `form2=PhysAddressForm()`. И обращайтесь к ним также в темплейтах `form1.name`, `form2.address`. Вот только у вас класс  `AddressClass`, а вы берете модель `PhysicalAddress`

Comment: @SergBocharov, а в представлении какой класс использовать?

Comment: Я же не знаю вашей модели данных, по предоставленным данным вам нужен класс представляющий модель `AddressClass` соответственно используйте `model = models.AddressClass`

Comment: @SergBocharov, я не знаю как вьюху описать. а модели описаны вначале - Industry,AddressClass(PhysicalAddress),Entity. а BaseModel просто содержит доп аттрибуты и наследуется от models.Model.

Comment: А как вы вообще ее пытались описать?